# RecyclerView jump to top when scrolled up

Tags: android, mobile, android-recyclerview

My recyclerView was jumping right to the beginning when scrolled up no matter how far from the top my scroll position was.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my images were not being loaded as fast as I scrolled up. So the fix for this issue was to put a placeholder image in my image binding. I am using Picasso so the fix was like this in my adapter:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(
        currentMovie.getBaseUrl()+ currentMovie.getPosterPath()
).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_star).into(mPoster);
```